# How to export the Tabulator Grid data with formatting and styles

Tags: tabulator

I am using the tabulator 5.4 version to bind the data in tabular format.So my query is when i am exporting the data in to xlsx in tabulator then the data is properly getting export but the formatter like (Money,$ sign,background color)is not showing in excel only values is visible.

I have attached my Grid screenshot and the excel screen shot which i get after export.

Grid ScreenShot

[image: 1]

Excel ScreenShot

[image: 2]

So please let me know how to resolve this and get all formatters in excel..

I have tried accessFormatter  and many more things but the result which i want is not working